# How to parse xls file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xls

I need to read the xls file content from URL with javascript and parse the content in html.

I used

```
/* set up XMLHttpRequest */
var url = "http://localhost/charts/test/file-test.xls";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); 
oReq.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost')
```

but cors error is detected

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/charts/test/file-test.xls' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Any Help please :)

Answer (score -1):

cors is a safety mechanism in the browser as described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
you can install a [chrome extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) to disable this temporarly or you can disable this in [express](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)